# Good approach to run one time script

Tags: node.js, performance

I need some recommendation to run one time script.

Below are steps that i need to do

- 100 online images (i have array for this)
- download and put to my working folder

What is a good approach to do this :- (below are my thoughts)

- write script and run it from terminal ?
- one time Cron job?

I'm using Node.js

Comment: Just run the script once. No need for a cron job, unless you want to run it multiple times.

Comment: You can make it general by creating API endpoint so that whenever you want, you can pass the links and it will provide the same functionality on local plus it will work remotely if you want it to be.

Comment: "one time Cron job" makes no sense. Cron is intended to schedule job to run periodically. If you want to run your script one time, just run it... one time.

Comment: unless you need to run this script at a time where no one is working and you cannot access their server at night, you can simply run this script once.

Answer (score 0):

No need of batch, just write a CLI and run it in background

Using async.queue, you can define how many worker functions can run in parallel.And you can push your image urls in the async queue object and the worker threads will parallely download the images fast and you can save them to you ur disk.

Ref: 
Processing a large dataset in less than 100 lines of Node.js with async.queue
https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/processing-a-large-dataset-in-less-than-100-lines-of-node-js-with-async-queue-9766a78fa088

Code sample : https://gist.github.com/sararob/275b252d1eda3a5baa27d6464d2f2198

Ref: https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#queue

concurrency number
an integer for determining how many worker functions should be run in parallel. This property can be changed after a queue is created to alter the concurrency on-the-fly.

Code sample :

// The queue sends the image ID to callVision() and writes the response to a local file
// once the entire queue has finished processing

```
let q = async.queue(callVision, 20);

q.push(imageIds, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
});
```